# accessing property values using Alpine.data in a x-for

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I am loading the values from the API and storing them in the data object and loading it into a div with x-init.
So i can loop through the data. It is working and get the values of person.name but when i try to access another property of person nothing happens. It will only output the top x-text in the template.

How come i cant access person.name and person.height at the same time when they both exist?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div x-data="dropdown" class="wrapper">
      <div x-init="toggle" class="scroll-text">
        <h1>STAR WARS API</h1>
        <template x-for="person in data">
          <div x-text="person.name"></div>
          <div x-text="person.height"></div>
        </template>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {
        async function loadJSON(url) {
          const response = await fetch(url);
          return await response.json();
        }

        Alpine.data("dropdown", () => ({
          data: [],
          async toggle() {
            const resp = await loadJSON("https://swapi.dev/api/people/");

            this.data = resp.results;
          },
        }));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<template>` element [must contain only one root element](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/for). So wrap it with e.g. an outer `<div>` or restructure a bit like this (for simple text):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div x-data="dropdown" class="wrapper">
      <div x-init="toggle" class="scroll-text">
        <h1>STAR WARS API</h1>
        <template x-for="person in data">
          <div x-text="`${person.name} - ${person.height} cm`"></div>
        </template>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener("alpine:init", () => {
        async function loadJSON(url) {
          const response = await fetch(url);
          return await response.json();
        }

        Alpine.data("dropdown", () => ({
          data: [],
          async toggle() {
            const resp = await loadJSON("https://swapi.dev/api/people/");

            this.data = resp.results;
          },
        }));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh boy should have known, thaks alot again mate!